# Removing cookies from a domain, plus it's www. and . versions

Tags: php, cookies

I am attempting to remove a cookie named `login` from my website in order to log someone out of a system. However, multiple "instances" of the same/a similar cookie seem to be persisting that I cannot access through PHP.

Here is my current code, with lots of test dumps to see what's going on:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
echo '</pre>';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']))
{
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie)
    {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time() - 3600);
        setcookie($name, '', time() - 3600, '/');
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
echo '</pre>';

// header('Location: index.php4');
exit();
```

However, the `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` contains **exactly** the same information in the second dump as it does in the first. I am utilising the [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to try and remove these cookies.

Using Google Chrome I can inspect the cookies, and I can see three instances of the same / a similar cookie:

```
Name: login
Content: deleted
Domain: www.example.com
Path: /login

Name: login
Content: deleted
Domain: www.example.com
Path: /

Name: login
Content: id|random_hash|other_stuff
Domain: .example.com
Path: /
```

Why am I able to remove the cookies from `www.example.com` but not from `.example.com`? It doesn't seem to matter if I access the logout script from `www.example.com` or `example.com`, I cannot access `.example.com`'s cookies.

Comment: Is your browser set to ignore third party cookies?

Comment: Try to write your `setcookie` function like this one (with domain) `setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/", ".example.com");`

Comment: _“However, the $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] contains exactly the same information in the second dump as it does in the first”_ - of course it does, because _nothing has changed_. You have only instructed PHP to send the headers to delete those cookies -  but that does of course not change what cookies the client has already send in the distant past, when it made the request that triggered the _current_ run of this script. Only after the _next_ requests this _can_ change.